# Preguntas sobre Diagrama de Clases

Tags: uml

[image: Diagrama de Clases]

Según el diagrama de arriba, tengo que responder a unas preguntas (verdadero o falso y argumentando) pero hay alguna que no me queda del todo claro y son las siguientes.

1ª Cada instancia de la clase F colecciona al menos una instancia de Clase G y otra de Clase H, pero no necesariamente.
Yo diría que es falsa, puesto que si que es necesario que haya una instancia de G y de H mínimo para cada instancia de F.

2ª Cada instancia de Clase F colecciona al menos una instancia de Clase G o de Clase H, pero no necesariamente una de cada tipo.
Falsa puesto que la instancia de F necesita al menos una de G y otra de H.

3ª Del total de las instancias de Clase A que existen en un momento dado, sólo una se relaciona con instancias de la clase F.
Verdadero puesto que solo hay 1 instancia de A que se pueda relacionar con 0 más de F, pongamos el ejemplo de Empresa(Clase A)---Trabajadores(Clase F)

Quería saber si las respuestas están bien o si me equivoco, ya que tengo alguna duda al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

En este ejemplo lo podemos ver:

- ZonaTematica sería F
- Atracción sería G
- Alojamiento sería H

[image: Ejemplo]

1. **Falso.** En cada ZonaTematica tiene que existir necesariamente una Atracción y un Alojamiento. Por otro lado, al ser una composición, las instnacias de Atracción y Alojamiento no podrían existir sin la existencia de la instancia ZonaTematica
2. **Falso.** Por lo mismo que antes
3. **Verdadero.** No es más que mirar la cardinalidad

Comment: Otra pregunta, que la Clase H tenga una composición fuerte con la clase F, no quiere decir que H herede de esta última verdad?

Comment: Exacto, piensa en mi ejemplo: Alojamiento NO hereda de una ZonaTematica. Lo que hace la composición "fuerte" es la necesidad de que exista ZonaTematica para que exista Alojamiento.

Comment: Entiendo, ante todo muchas gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta, también entiendo que cuando se crea una Zona Temática siguiendo tu ejemplo, es necesario crear como mínimo 1 atracción y 1 alojamiento.

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos. Si, pero eso se debe a la cardinalidad, no a que sea una composición. Recuerda que si te ha sido útil votes las respuestas (no solo la mía sino de todo el que te ayude).

Comment: Muy bien todo claro, muchas gracias y muy amable, por curiosidad que estudias o has estudiado?

Comment: Ingenieria informatica